# Need help for mysql query

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL table I have a column named `member_id`.  That column stores values like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

I need to check that by using

```
SELECT * 
FROM member 
WHERE 5 IN member_id
```

It's not working well. Please help me write a SQL query that will find the appropriate results.

Comment: Post some code you have tries and try and explain better what you're tryin to achieve

Comment: You should provide more specific information here. Please provide the table schema and the exact query, along with a more specific definition of "not working well".

Comment: I have attempted to tidy up his post, but it is currently awaiting peer review, I also up voted him because downvoting is just mean.

Comment: Thanks for all my friends. I keep in my mind above advises. I dont know fluent english, thats the problem. I am very happy to hear your instructions and i will follow up. once again i thanked for ScottAnderson.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET(5, member_id)
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with MySQL, but wouldn't you want to do something like `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(5, member_id) > 0`?  Maybe MySQL evaluates everything `> 0` as truthy and this isn't explicitly required, though.

Comment: Really?
I'm sure he just needs SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE member_id = 5 ...
But then again, I could be wrong since the question is pretty unclear...

Comment: @ScottAnderson: In `MySQL`, `BOOLEAN` is in fact an integer.

Comment: can you please tell related question, If i want to check the member id not in specified column. that is 
"select * from member where find_not_in_set(5,member_id)"

Comment: @Thilak: `WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(5, member_id)`

Answer (score 1):

Quassnoi's method is preferred for MySQL, but for a portable cross-platform technique, you can do this:

```
select * 
from member 
where member_id = '5' 
    or member_id like '5,%' 
    or member_id like '%,5,%' 
    or member_id like '%,5'
```

This assumes there is no extra whitespace in your data.

Comment: Isn't if I have `55,1` & `8,5,5,6` as input I will have both row after executing query??

Comment: @FahimParkar No. Which clause do you think could match the first case?

Comment: Isn't `member_id like '5,%'` will not consider `55,1`??

Comment: Even `member_id like '%,5'` will conside if I have `4,55,6,4`

Comment: @FahimParkar No, neither of those will match.

Comment: why? they will match. Just curious why they will not match?

Comment: @FahimParkar `'5,%'` means the value must start with `5,` and `55,1` does not. Similarly, `'%,5'` means the value must end with `,5` and `4,55,6,4` does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE member_id LIKE '%5%'
```

Comment: This would match `15` or `50` as well.

Comment: Yes I realize that, I don't know what the range of values in that column is, it works for his posted sample, I don't know that it is any more complicated than that